# Unable to separate text data in csv. (Separate text with @ so that it becomes two columns)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, delimiter

According to Gran, the company has no plans to move all production to Russia, although that is where the company is growing .@neutral

The above is the text and I want to separate it with @ so that it will produce two columns

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'F:\Sentences_50Agree.csv', sep='@', header=None)
```

I tried the above but it's not working. It's showing only 1 column with total text including @neutral

Comment: Cannot reproduce, if I create file with above sentence, running your code I get dataframe with 2 columns.

Comment: can you please post the code? It would be helpful

Comment: I posted the code I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


s = 'According to Gran, the company has no plans to move all production to Russia, although that is where the company is growing .@neutral'
print( pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='@', header=None) )
```

Prints:

```
                                                   0        1
0  According to Gran, the company has no plans to...  neutral
```

---

Or with file:

```
print( pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='@', header=None) )
```

Comment: But how to do for total data frame?? There 1000's of rows which contains text like this.

Comment: @NithinReddy I don't understand. What do you mean by "total data frame" ?

Comment: Ya last one is working and better add parameter 'encoding="ISO-8859-1"'